# What do the React docs mean by the following statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

> *In our experience, thinking about how the UI should look at any given moment, rather than how to change it over time, eliminates a whole class of bugs.*

From [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html)

From my understanding, this means that React only updates what's necessary, rather than destroying and re-constructing the entire DOM tree again. Am I wrong?

Can anyone please help me understand the quoted statement?

Thanks.

Comment: Your interpretation is right. The responsibility of the application is to declare how the UI should look at any point in time. The responsibility of React is to make the necessary changes to the DOM.

Comment: Please keep in mind, if one of the answers works for you, please mark them as the answer to help other peeps in the community to find their solution easier if they facing the same issue. You can do this by using grey marks (tick) beside answers (you can only choose one), for more information please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

> From my understanding, this means that React only updates what's necessary, rather than destroying and re-constructing the entire DOM tree again. Am I wrong?

If you want to know the short answer, I have to say it is **true**, *React will update the necessary elements in DOM whenever it needed.*

But if you want to know how it's done, and when React will update the DOM and its element I have to it is varying to different several things, like *project architecture*, using *proper methods* (proper hooks in functional component eg. `useCallback`, `useMemo`, and so on) and so on.

### When it truly gets rerender then?

As far as I know, there are two ways React finds out when to rerender the DOM.

1. Passing elements to `ReactDOM.render`
2. Update a **state**

### What is ReactDOM.render?

This will call the `render()` method from `react-dom` (Where we usually import it as ReactDOM) and it will render a React element into the DOM in the supplied container and return a reference to the component (or returns `null` for stateless components). Also if the React element was previously rendered into the container, this will perform an update on it and only mutate the DOM as necessary to reflect the latest React element.

### What does state mean?

The **state** object is where you store property values that belong to the component. So when you got a component and that component has their own specific variables where changing them should affect the DOM you should use it, then whenever **state** gets changes the component will be updated.

**So what I even talk about project architecture and this stuff, when I didn't mention anything about it above?**

Let's say we got a project with one parent component and 3 child component just like this:

```
Component 1  

- |- Component 2


- - |- Component 3


- - - |- Component 4
```

So whenever you a **state** in `Component 4` all of the DOM elements will be get rerendered, why then? Because `Component 4` is a child of `Component 3` and so on, so when the child **state** gets change it will force the parent to rerender then the whole DOM will rerender once per **state** change.

**Final Note**

So, at last, we should be always considered a good architecture and hierarchy for our project or when it necessarily use built-in methods like `useMemo` to avoid such a thing.